# How can I paste text appending it to the end of each line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

If I have file1.txt which contains the following:

```
Line 1.1;
Line 1.2;
Line 1.3;
```

and file2.txt with the following

```
Line 2.1;
Line 2.2;
Line 2.3;
```

I want to copy all the lines of file2.txt and paste it to file1.txt in a way that stays like this:

```
Line 1.1;Line 2.1;
Line 1.2;Line 2.2;
Line 1.3;Line 2.3;
```

how can I do it?

edit:

The lines can have some variation of character numbers like if file1 have

```
Cabo de Força MD9 1.5M NBR14136 3X0,50 – 5815;R$ 8,90;
Empire Cabo HDMI 1.4TV 3D M/M 2m Gold – 2304;R$ 13,90;
Filtro de Linha SMS 4 Tomadas 1,3M Bivolt 62328;R$ 33,90;
```

and file2 have:

```
Placa de Vídeo ASUS RADEON RX 560 STRIX ROG STRIX-RX560-4G-GAMING 4GB GDDR5 PCI-EXP; R$ 759,00;
Fonte Corsair CX600 600W CP-9020048-WW ATX 2.3 PFC Ativo; R$ 339,00;
Memória DDR4 Kingston HyperX Fury HX424C15FB/8 8GB 2400MHz; R$ 429,00;
```

Just as an example.

Comment: Do the lines always have the same number of characters? If the number of columns is fixed there's an easy solution using visual block mode... If it's not, can you [edit] the post to include examples with different number of columns?

Comment: With uneven line lengths I'd do it by adding some padding to the longest line in the target file, `set virtualedit=block`, ctrl-v to select and yank in the source file, then ctrl-v in the target file selecting the rightmost column (which ve=block allows) and put.

Comment: Man, absolutely no one looks for duplicates anymore do they. :D

Comment: Link to the question itself rather than jumping to my answer which is one of several: [Add a block of text to end of lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16094)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a *nix system, I would use `paste` first:

```
%!paste - file2.txt
```

And then you have lots of options to get rid of the tabs. You could add `| sed 's/<C-v><Tab>//g'` to the end of the pipeline above, or use the (very similar!) command

```
%substitute/\t//g
```

which permits abbreviation as `:%s/\t//g`.

Comment: There's already an answer using paste in the page I linked.

Comment: @BLayer that there is; I didn't read all the comments. (And were it not for the date on that post, I would have been surprised I wasn't the one to write it!) Wonder if it's a good dupe.

Comment: I put it up for a vote so we'll see.

Comment: @BLayer re dupes, i will if i can remember seeing one, or if im convinced one must exist. Otherwise not so much 

Comment: When I started (here but mostly Unix & Linux) I remember there being an emphasis on it. Now and then a person would even get "scolded" if they clearly answered without any effort to check. That's how my thinking about it was formed. :)

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I wanted but is the closest one, and the only one I managed to make it work

Comment: A ringing endorsement! ;) You tried the solutions in the post considered duplicate? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yank the second paragraph (e.g. `yip`).
2. Visually select the first paragraph.
3. Leave visual mode.
4. Run this Ex command:

   ```
   let l = split(@", "\n") | *s/$/\=remove(l, 0)
   ```

It works even if the lines on which you want to append the lines of the second paragraph are not contiguous.

For example, suppose your first paragraph is:

```
Line 1.1;
leave
Line 1.2;
me
Line 1.3;
alone
```

Repeat the exact same steps; but in the fourth one, use this Ex command instead:

```
let l = split(@", "\n") | *s/^Line.*\zs/\=remove(l, 0)
                             ^--------^
                             only append text on lines starting with "Line"
```