# combining multiple lines

Tags: substitute, join

I have a text file of X ips and X files that looks like:

```
ip1
ip2
ip3
some_dir/file1
some_dir/file2
some_dir/file3
```

I'd like to combine the lines into a csv format, like:

```
ip1,some_dir/file1
ip2,some_dir/file2
ip3,some_dir/file3
```

Any suggestions on how this could be on? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. See if the answers here help: [Add a block of text to end of lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16094) (and don't forget to upvote any that do :)

Comment: Hint: in the accepted answer under "Dash-delimited" is a solution that should work for your problem. First, put a blank line between your two blocks, then put the cursor on the `i` of `ip1`. Then use the solution as written except change the space-dash-space to a comma.

Comment: @BLayer hey, thanks for the help! What you linked does look like what I'm trying to do but I'm not familiar with how to use the command, it looks like a list of instructions.

Comment: Right, here's the (amended) sequence: `mt<C-V>}mb<BS>$A,<Esc>gvd'bjPkd't`. While in Normal mode you'll want to type those characters literally except for the parts of the form `<X>`. Those are, respectively, Ctrl-V, Backspace and Escape.

Comment: Oh ok awesome, that worked! I didn't realized it was key strokes. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. You're welcome. (And I just realized that despite what I wrote in my first comment you don't have enough rep to upvote! LOL.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!